# Предоставление разрешения работы с Usb устройством при обработке в сервисе Android

Tags: android, usb, android-service, android-permissions

Есть необходимость обрабатывать данные USB устройства через сервис (foreground service). При первом запуске всплывает окно с разрешением использования этого USB устройства, нажимаем "ОК" и после этого, если закрыть приложение и оставить работать только сервис, все корректно отрабатывает. Но во время работы USB устройство должно периодически отключаться и через какое-то время опять выходить на связь. Сервис при этом не закрывается и ожидает появления USB устройства. Когда USB устройство появляется, то необходимо опять делать запрос на разрешение с работой USB устройства, то есть опять давать подтверждение через всплывающие окно.
Вопрос в следующем, возможно ли как-то сохранить разрешение на работу с USB устройством, данное при первом запуске, чтобы не было необходимости при каждом подключении устройства давать разрешение ?
В манифесте указан фильтр с устройствами

```
        <service
        android:name=".MainService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </service>
```

device_filter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24597"/>
</resources>
```

Инициализация USB устройства:

```
        private val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"
        ...
        val usbManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
        val usbDevice = usbManager.deviceList.values.iterator().next()

        if (!usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
            val mPermissionIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0)
            usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent)
        }

        val usbConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice)

        serial = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(usbDevice, usbConnection)

        checkInitUSB = true
```

Встречал на [форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168148/usb-host-mode-device-access-permission-granted-but-not-remembered) так же предположение, что разрешение не сохраняется в связи с разными идентификаторами при подключении. Действительно ли из-за этого, непонятно.

Comment: Покажите файл `device_filter.xml`

Comment: Добавил описание device_filter.xml в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, только в манифесте должно быть указано так:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="<version>" />
...
<application>
  <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
    <activity ...>
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

источник https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory#manifest-example